# Quantifying the symmetry of a signal

Tags: signal-analysis

You did it using the norm of the function(signal).

I want to measure this symmetry by subtracting each point of my signal from the flipped one. My question is about the way to normalize this difference. Can standard deviation of the signal be a good option? ( I do not want to divide it by the value of max).

Comment: Symmetry in time you mean? I.e. whether reversed signal matches the original one?

Comment: Adding to @jojek is your question related to a specific center point (half-way of the signal), in time or amplitude? "Normalize" may mean a unitless measure. Standard deviation is not unitless. Could you provide different examples of more or less symmetric signals (with your judgement)

Answer (score 1):

A signal can be decomposed into the sum of an even (symmetric) signal plus an odd (anti-symmetric) signal.  One measure of symmetry of the signal might be the ratio between of the energy in the even decomposition to the energy of the total signal.